# Process terminates after SSH logout on windows server

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, powershell, process

I have a **Windows server 2016** machine that needs to run an file that uses the cli, remotely **using SSH**.

It is known that logging out of an SSH connection terminates processes that were started by the ssh user. On linux machines, one may use solutions such as `nohup` or `screen`, resulting a process not being killed once logging off.

Such solutions  won't work on windows machines though, and I'm looking for a way to prevent a process from getting terminated once logged out.

- My client is an *Ubuntu machine*
- My Windows server 2016 runs *OpenSHH*, with *PowerShell* as a default shell
- My program is set to work in daemon mode, and no cmd or powershell windows are left open
- Using `Get-Process -Name proc_name` shows the process is indeed running
- Using `Get-Process` after SSH logout yields no such process

Things I also tried:

- Running the `.exe` file  using `cmd`.
- Running a `.bat` and `.ps` files that starts the `.exe` with its arguments.

Is there a way to tackles this problem on a windows machine?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Windows OS version. PS runs in the context of the user who started it. Killing the user kills the process. You should look to using PowerShell Background jobs.

Comment: @postanote Assuming the local user who currently runs the server is `Administrator`, does the SSH user (that logged in as user `Administrator`) considered a different user? This may explain why when logging off the connection also kills processes started by that user..

Comment: Yes, these would be two different PowerShell sessions/instances/user contexts. If you are trying ot run PowerShell in the context of the logged-on user, Windows security boundaries prevent that. You'd need 3rdP, like Sysinternals tools or the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending much time digging for solutions, I found the absolute correct way of doing so using PowerShell.

It seems like it is one of those cmdlets less used or documented online, and is almost impossible to figure out on your own using the MSDN documentation, unless you're already very familiar with the huge world of `Wmi Objects`.

### In short:

Assuming I  have a program `foo.exe` that needs to run on background with the arguments `-a`, `-b` and `bar`, I should be using the exact command:

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -Path 'Win32_Process' -Name Create -ArgumentList 'C:\Users\foo\Desktop\foo.exe -a -b bar'
```

Of course if your exe is a "known" exe (either by default, such as notepad or ping) or added by you, a full path is not needed when  using the `-ArgumentList` and exe name would be sufficient (notepad, ping, and etc..).

### Additional parameters:

`Invoke-WmiMethod` supports additional parameters such as `-Credential`,  `-ComputerName` (a good way to use a local PS to `Invoke` something on a remote machine without using SSH) , `-Impersonation` and many [more documented here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/invoke-wmimethod?view=powershell-5.1).

### Cmdlet syntax explanation and additional cmdlet tools:

- The `-Path` argument directs to a `WmiObject` name. There are **dozens** of `WmiObjects`, each with many `Methods` and `Properties`.
- The `-Name` argument directs the used `Method`.
- To list all available `Wmi-Objects` use `Get-WmiObject -List` (very difficult to locate your needed object this way).
- To list and view all available `Win32_Process` `Methods` and `Properties` use

```
Get-WmiObject -List |where{$_.name -match '^Win32_Process$'}
```

This will return an output of this structure:

```
   NameSpace: ROOT\cimv2

Name                                Methods              Properties
----                                -------              ----------
Win32_Process                       {Create, Terminat... {Caption, CommandLine, CreationClassName, CreationDate...}
```

And of course using `|Select-Object -ExpandProperty (_your_property_here_)` will reveal all available `Methods` such as `Create` we used in the command above, and all available `Properties` (which we did not use).